# Календарный вывод количества товаров

Tags: sql, sql-server

Решаю задачу, где имеется таблица Move с полями MoveDate и MoveCount. Таблица Move забита примерно следующими данными:

```
MoveDate    | MoveCount
________________________________
30.07.2015  | +5
30.07.2015  | -2
31.07.2015  | +1
31.07.2015  | +9
31.07.2015  | +7
31.07.2015  | -8
31.07.2015  | +5
01.08.2015  | +9
03.08.2015  | -7
03.08.2015  | +5
03.08.2015  | -7 
07.08.2015  | +2
08.08.2015  | +5
```

В задаче сказано, что необходимо сделать выборки, где составить еженедельник изменений, даже если этих изменений не было. Например, с 02.07 на 03.07 изменений не происходило. Так что баланс остался тот же. И вывести даже те дни, в которых не было операций и изменения количества фильмов.

Должно быть так:

```
MoveDate    | MoveCount
________________________________
30.07.2015  | 3
31.07.2015  | 17
01.08.2015  | 26
02.08.2015  | NULL
03.08.2015  | 17
04.08.2015  | NULL
05.08.2015  | NULL
06.08.2015  | NULL
07.08.2015  | 19
08.08.2015  | 24
```

Я решать начал таким образом, создал дополнительно таблицу CDate_ куда каждый день создается новая запись с текущей датой. Событие создается триггером. Структура этой таблицы такова:

```
CDate
________________________
id  | Date_ | Count_
```

Когда я пишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT CDate_.Date_, Sum(M.MoveCount_) AS SumMoveCount_
FROM MovementGoods AS M RIGHT JOIN CDate_ ON M.MoveDate_=CDate_.Date_
GROUP BY CDate_.Date_;
```

То результат получаю совокупность дат, где фиксируются изменения в балансе-количества товара. Если они есть, то отмечается положительный или отрицательный баланс на тот день.

```
Date_    | SumMoveCount_
________________________________
29.07.2015  | 
30.07.2015  | 3
31.07.2015  | 14
01.08.2015  | 9
02.08.2015  | 
03.08.2015  | -9
04.08.2015  | 
05.08.2015  | 
06.08.2015  | 
07.08.2015  | 2
08.08.2015  | -5
```

Однако это не дает мне желаемого, что я хотел бы видеть. Использую, как стандартный SQL, так и возможно T-SQL. Потому хотел бы спросить, можно ли как-то сделать то, что я показал во второй таблице, не прибегая к дополнительным таблицам. Я всех особенностей T-SQL не знаю, потому и спрашиваю. Сразу говорю, что не интересует перебор курсором или выполнение целой совокупностью запросов эту задачу. Я пока что сделал в виде вложенных запросов, но это однако, не совсем то, что я хотел бы получить. Буду благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сгенерировать даты в диапазоне можно рекурсивным CTE запросом, без использования дополнительных таблиц:

```
WITH Q(D) AS
(
  SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2015,07,01) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,D)
  FROM    Q
  WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,1,D) < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,08,31)
)

select Q.D, Sum(M.MoveCount_) AS SumMoveCount_
  from Q
  left join MovementGoods AS M ON M.MoveDate_=Q.D
 group by Q.D
```

Comment: Отличный запрос! Плюсую ваш ответ.

Comment: Не работает ваш код к сожалению из-за того, что функция DATEFROMPARTS не определена, хотя синтаксически выглядит правильно. Я в ответах переделал на свой вариант. но и там есть загвоздка. Прочтите, ее, если не трудно

Comment: @IntegralAL А зачем так сложно с какими то convert. cast(datetime, '2016-08-01') только посмотреть точный формат даты для него надо. код у меня работает, судя по информации в интернете функция datefromparts появилась в 2012 sql server

Comment: @IntegralAL Какая у вас версия SQL Sever ? информации с какой версии работает рекурсивный CTE найти не могу ...

Comment: Версия ms sql 2008 года. Тут дело даже не в рекурсии. Я протестил другую рекурсию где просто запрос много раз исполняется. Она работает. А тут ошибку выдает, что D неопределенна.

Comment: @IntegralAL Попробуйте несколько иной синтаксис, букву D объявить в with. поменял в ответе

Comment: да все заработало. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю у тебя имеется таблица, где значатся изменения и тебе нужно получить даты, где изменений так же не было?

На ум приходит LEFT JOIN, где то почему ты соединяешься- это дата.

Для этого тебе нужно получить список дат.

Я нашел вот такую функцию https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function

На вход подаешь минимальную дату и максимальную и получаешь список дат, затем можешь воспользоваться LEFT JOIN и по идее получишь желаемый результат.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В своем примере, я соединяю так: RIGHT JOIN CDate_ ON M.MoveDate_=CDate_.Date_. Однако это не то, что мне нужно. Без каких-то сторонних функций, нельзя оформить это запросом со вложениями?

Comment: По идее та функция является табличной и ее можно скопипастить в подзапрос и должно работать.