# Как в t-sql получить таблицу с датами от одной даты до другой?

Tags: sql-server

```
DateRange('9/28/2017', '10/4/2017')
```

Чтобы вернула таблицу с таким содержанием. Есть что-то похожее?

```
9/28/2017
9/29/2017
9/30/2017
10/1/2017
10/2/2017
10/3/2017
10/4/2017
```

А вообще мне просто выборку по дням нужно сделать. Просто сгруппировать по дате нельзя, не все дни присутствуют, а нужно для них получить 0.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Календарный вывод количества товаров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562414/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @Mike, возможно, но тут уже дали более лаконичный ответ.

Comment: Да, но данный ответ - это процедура, которая заранее заполняет таблицу (хоть и временную). А в том ответе единый запрос генерации, который позволяет прямо в нем сделать join с вашими данными и выполнить все за одно действие без всяких временных таблиц. И дело в общем то даже не в этом, любой из подходов можно использовать. но факт остается фактом - вопрос повторен, значит один должен быть закрыт

Comment: @Mike простите, отвечая на ваш вопрос: без циклов по возможности, используя мощь реляционной алгебры

Comment: @agimgal предлагаю воспользоваться реляционным подходом к генерации дат, у меня аналогично генерируется view с календарем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '9/28/2017'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '10/4/2017'

DECLARE @count DATETIME = @startDate;
DECLARE @res TABLE(DATETIME [Date]);

WHILE @count <= @endDate
BEGIN
    INSERT 
    INTO @res ([Datetime])
    VALUES (@count)
    SET @count  = DATEADD(day, 1, @count)
END

SELECT *
FROM @res
```

Answer (score 2):

Последовательность дат можно сформировать непосредственно в запросе или сделать view:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '20170101';
DECLARE @end_date DATE = '20171231';

WITH cte10 AS
(
    SELECT n AS ID
    FROM (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) numbers(n)
),
cte100 AS
(
    SELECT c1.id * 10 + c2.id AS id
     FROM cte10 c1, cte10 c2
),
cte100000 AS 
(
     SELECT c1.id * 1000 + c2.id*10 + c3.id AS id
     FROM cte100 c1, cte100 c2, cte10 c3
),
cte_dates AS 
(
     SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, id, '19900101') AS DATE) AS dt
     FROM cte100000
)
SELECT
    dt
FROM cte_dates
WHERE dt BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Можно сделать функцию
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FillDate] 
(
    @start_date as [date],
    @end_date   as [date] 
)
RETURNS 
@FillDate TABLE (
[date] [date]
)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (@start_date <= @end_date)
BEGIN  
insert into @FillDate (date) values (@start_date)
set @start_date = DateAdd(dd,1,@start_date)
END
    RETURN 
END
==========
и использовать её так

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FillDate] (
   GetDate()
  ,EoMonth(getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FromDate SMALLDATETIME, @ToDate SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT @FromDate = '20190101', @ToDate = getdate();
WITH Days(D) AS
(
 SELECT @FromDate WHERE @FromDate <= @ToDate
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,D) FROM Days WHERE D < @ToDate
)
SELECT D FROM Days ORDER BY D desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```