# Посчитать записи, активные в заданный год и месяц

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL

Есть табличка, содержащая поля OPEN_TIME и CLOSE_TIME

```
 ID    |   OPEN_TIME             |    CLOSE_TIME
-------+-------------------------+------------------------
 1     | 2016-08-21 21:40:00.000 | NULL
 2     | 2016-09-27 22:30:00.000 | 2016-10-29 23:30:00.000
 3     | 2016-10-27 23:20:00.000 | 2016-10-28 24:10:00.000
 4     | 2016-10-27 24:10:00.000 | NULL
```

Надо, для заданных года и месяца получить записи, для которых OPEN_TIME раньше либо совпадает по году и месяцу, а CLOSE_TIME позже либо совпадает по году и месяцу (либо NULL)

Например для Y=2016, M=09 получить 2 записи (1 и 2), а для M=10, 4 записи(1, 2, 3 и 4)

А получить хочется такое в итоге (задав дату начала и окончания периода)

```
  YEAR  |  MONTH | COUNT
--------+--------+-------
   2016 |   7    |  0
   2016 |   8    |  1   (1)
   2016 |   9    |  2   (1, 2)
   2016 |   10   |  4   (1, 2, 3, 4)
   2016 |   11   |  2   (1, 4)
```

Так как конкретно с MS SQL работал очень мало, то надеюсь на вашу экспертизу.

1) Можно ли такое получить одним запросом, без процедур?

2) Если нельзя, то как грамотней организовать граничные условия для дат?

**UPD** набросал вот такой монструоз, гляньте плиз, нигде не накосячил?

```
SELECT
  t1.base,
  SUM(t2.cnt) AS cnt,
  QC_PROJECT
FROM (
       SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, nbr - 1, '20160101'), 'yyyyMM') AS base
       FROM (
              SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                     OVER (
                       ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
              FROM sys.columns c
            ) nbrs
       WHERE nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20160101', GETDATE())
     ) AS t1,
  (
    SELECT
      format(OPEN_TIME, 'yyyyMM')                     AS start,
      format(ISNULL(CLOSE_TIME, GETDATE()), 'yyyyMM') AS finish,
      COUNT(*)                                        AS cnt,
      QC_PROJECT
    FROM [SM9].[dbo].HPCDEFECT2M1
    WHERE 1 = 1
          AND NOT STATUS = 'Отклонен'
          AND (NOT QC_FR = 'Y' OR QC_FR IS NULL)
          AND NOT OPEN_TIME IS NULL
    GROUP BY
      format(OPEN_TIME, 'yyyyMM'),
      format(ISNULL(CLOSE_TIME, GETDATE()), 'yyyyMM'),
      QC_PROJECT
  ) t2
WHERE base >= start AND base <= finish
GROUP BY base, QC_PROJECT
ORDER BY QC_PROJECT, base
```

Comment: Ну отформатируйте даты в формат `YYYYMM` и сравнивайте, какие сложности-то?

Comment: `[s1,е1]`, `[s2,e2]` - два отрезка на числовой прямой. Они пересекаются, если: `s2 <= e1 && e2 >= s1`

Comment: @Akina сложности в незнании тонкостей работы с датами в MS SQL. Оно тут сильно отличается от того же mysql, оракла и прочих

Comment: @Igor 1) числовая прямая и объект DateTime - несколько разные вещи. Границы второго отрезка еще надо вычислить, ака 1 и последний день конкретного месяца

Comment: Чем то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562420/194569 делаете опорный запрос, который будет давать вам первые числа месяцев подряд на нужном вам интервале дат, потом по left join клеите к нему таблицу с данными, с условиями вроде open_time<=дата and coalesce(close_time, '3000-01-01') < дата+1 месяц`  (и последний день месяца совершенно не нужен, строгое меньше 1 числа следующего месяца даст тот же эффект)

Comment: @rjhdby `select format( [date] , 'yyyyMM') ...`

Comment: @Mike спасибо за наводку про опорный запрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, нигде я не напортачил с запросом?

Comment: вроде все нормально